# Array está retornando somente o último índice

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Criei um array que tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
    $arr = array(
    "cabecalho" => [
        "instrucoes" => array("Instrucao 1", "Instrucao 2", "Instrucao 3", "Instrucao N"),
        "dadosAluno" => array("codigoAluno" => "123456789", "nomeCompleto" => "John Doe"),
        "dadosProva" => array(
            "curso" => "Administracao",
            "disciplina" => array("tipo" => "Modulo", "nome" => "Etica"),
            "periodoRealizacao" => array("inicio" => "2020-07-01", "fim" => "2020-07-31"),
            "periodoRealizacao2" => array("inicio" => "2020-07-01", "fim" => "2020-07-31"),
            "tempoDeProvaEmSegundos" => "3600"
        ),
        "UrlLogin" => "https://wwwexemplo.com/login/",
        "UrlRetorno" => "https://wwwexemplo.com/retorno/"
    ],
    "questoes" => [[
        "idExterno" => "1",
        "pergunta" => "Pergunta 1",
        "respostasPossiveis" => array(
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 1")),
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 1")),
        ),
        "idExterno" => "2",
        "pergunta" => "Pergunta 2",
        "respostasPossiveis" => array(
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 2")),
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 2")),
        ),
    ]],
);
```

Ao executar o comando: `echo '<pre><br />';print_r($arr['questoes']);echo '</pre>';die();` está retornando a segunte estrutura

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idExterno] => 2
            [pergunta] => Pergunta 2
            [respostasPossiveis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [opcao] => A
                            [texto] => Resposta A da pergunta 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [opcao] => A
                            [texto] => Resposta A da pergunta 2
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Ele não está exibindo o primeiro array que contem o `idExterno` igual a 1 e todo seu conteúdo da pergunta 1 não é exibido.

O último valor está substibuindo o primeiro ou todos que houverem antes, como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o array tem duas chaves chamadas `idExterno`. Basicamente o que você fez foi (omitindo alguns dados para ficar mais simples de visualizar):

```
[[
    "idExterno" => "1",
    "pergunta" => "Pergunta 1",
    "respostasPossiveis" => array( ... ),
    "idExterno" => "2",
    "pergunta" => "Pergunta 2",
    "respostasPossiveis" => array( ... ),
]],
```

Repare que todas as chaves estão no mesmo array, ou seja, tem dois `idExterno`, duas `pergunta`, etc.

Se a ideia era ter 2 elementos, cada um com o seu `idExterno` e demais chaves, então teria que adicionar os colchetes no lugar correto:

```
[
  [
    "idExterno" => "1",
    "pergunta" => "Pergunta 1",
    "respostasPossiveis" => array( ... )
  ],  <-- aqui termina o array com idExterno 1
  [   <-- aqui começa o outro array, com idExterno 2
    "idExterno" => "2",
    "pergunta" => "Pergunta 2",
    "respostasPossiveis" => array( ... ),
  ]
],
```

Portanto, ficaria assim:

```
$arr = array(
    "cabecalho" => [
        "instrucoes" => array("Instrucao 1", "Instrucao 2", "Instrucao 3", "Instrucao N"),
        "dadosAluno" => array("codigoAluno" => "123456789", "nomeCompleto" => "John Doe"),
        "dadosProva" => array(
            "curso" => "Administracao",
            "disciplina" => array("tipo" => "Modulo", "nome" => "Etica"),
            "periodoRealizacao" => array("inicio" => "2020-07-01", "fim" => "2020-07-31"),
            "periodoRealizacao2" => array("inicio" => "2020-07-01", "fim" => "2020-07-31"),
            "tempoDeProvaEmSegundos" => "3600"
        ),
        "UrlLogin" => "https://wwwexemplo.com/login/",
        "UrlRetorno" => "https://wwwexemplo.com/retorno/"
    ],
    "questoes" => [
        [
          "idExterno" => "1",
          "pergunta" => "Pergunta 1",
          "respostasPossiveis" => array(
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 1")),
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 1")),
          )
        ],
        [
          "idExterno" => "2",
          "pergunta" => "Pergunta 2",
          "respostasPossiveis" => array(
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 2")),
            array("opcao" => "A", "texto" => utf8_encode("Resposta A da pergunta 2")),
          )
        ]
    ]
);

print_r($arr['questoes']);
```

E a saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idExterno] => 1
            [pergunta] => Pergunta 1
            [respostasPossiveis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [opcao] => A
                            [texto] => Resposta A da pergunta 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [opcao] => A
                            [texto] => Resposta A da pergunta 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idExterno] => 2
            [pergunta] => Pergunta 2
            [respostasPossiveis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [opcao] => A
                            [texto] => Resposta A da pergunta 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [opcao] => A
                            [texto] => Resposta A da pergunta 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!